# What is this Google Chrome icon appearing in the dock?

Tags: google-chrome

When I'm using Chrome browser sometimes two icons appear in the dock.  I know the one with dot (left) but what is the one with Mac icon (right)?  The right one just disappears if I click on it.  If I don't do anything the icon (right) will disappear after awhile.

I think this is handoff feature.

1. How do I know which device is sending the handoff to my Mac?
2. Can it be security hole if I click on it?
3. Since someone can send it to my Mac, can *my* mac accidentally send the handoff to other device? i.e. I'm concerned if the two or more devices are allowed to communicate bidirectionally.

[image]

Comment: hover over it to see if there's a tooltip. How many devices do you have ?

Comment: I believe this is handoff, and it should only work with your linked Macs/iOS devices with the same iCloud Account signed in. To enable handoff, both devices need to have wifi and bluetooth on. So if you turn off one of those, the icon should disappear. You can disable handoff permanently in System Preferences as well.

Comment: @anki I will try hover over next time.  I was on my MBP.  I have an iMac but I wasn't logged in when the icon popped up

Comment: @Avelj I was wondering about iCloud. Find My iPhone can find the iMac while I'm not logged in (right thing for the purpose!).  Is it considered that I'm signed in to iCloud?  Either way Chrome wasn't running in iMac.  I'm still puzzled why the icon popped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the icon you see on the right is Handoff from another computer that you are signed into and are near. That computer has a window open in a web browser. (I'm assuming you have Chrome as your default browser)

You can ignore it if you want, or select it to "hand off" what you are doing on the other computer to this current one.

To answer your questions;

1. The icon that you see there usually shows what device is "handing off" from. In this case, it's a desktop, not a mobile device.
2. Unless someone is using your computer without you knowing, it's probably not a security issue. This only is shared between computers that are signed in with the same iCloud account.
3. Someone can Airdrop something to you, but you have to agree to it. Airdropping from a computer that are are signed into with your iCloud account to another computer, also signed in with the same iCloud account, can just transfer files without asking. No third party can just send, or push, something to you without you agreeing to it.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have an iPhone, iMac and MBP. The icon indicates that the handoff was from the desktop is the first clue.  It seems to be from iMac.  Then again I wasn't logged on the iMac.  Does power-nap do something for Chrome while I was not logged in?  What criteria determines the "near"?  I think devices are "near" when they are reachable by bluetooth or discovered by Bonjour.  What if someone somewhere far away logged into iCloud using same user/pw?

Comment: When I say near, I mean what it says, within a close proximity to each other. It's like I'm handing you something physically. Think of it as if it only works if you're within the social distancing guidelines. Instead of 6ft, it's more like 12 to 15 feet, usually the distance that Bluetooth can reach. It will not work if someone signed into your account from across the void.